# The 404 icon is pushed to the top in the new 404 page

Tags: bug, 404-not-found

While visiting any deleted question, I see the icon of 404 is pushed to the top.

Screenshot:

[image: Preview]

Full Screenshot:

[image: Preview]

To reproduce, go to any deleted question (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836557/how-to-write-a-movie-review-program), if you are greater than 10K then use a private tab).

I am using a 1366 x 768 Laptop. Firefox 90.0.2.

Comment: Only repro'd using a really small window

Comment: Looks normal on my 4k monitor but as soon as I start to make the window small, it pops on top of the text and is indeed a little out of bounds. Not in the same way as shown in the picture though. EDIT: ah, if you shrink the window vertically it moves out of bounds. So this would happen on phones and maybe tablets in landscape orientation, probably.

Comment: Im using mobile phone to try this, its quite normal. but it does get pushed to the top when i enable dekstop mode

Comment: @Gimby I am using 1366 x 768 Laptop and it the bug is there.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour indeed, a vertical resolution of 768 is "small" nowadays. it goes a little far to call a styling issue caused by a small screen a bug. The usability of the site is not affected in any way, it just looks a little ugly.

Comment: @Gimby Hmmm. As far as I know, a good developer should develop something good for all screens and platforms; not just 4K screens. I am happy with my screen. I just won't buy a 4K monitor to see a good 404 icon in Stack Overflow because the developer can't just center the icon at all. Am I wrong in something?

Comment: @Gimby UI bugs are still bugs

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Custom 404 pages are gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367993)*

Comment: where is the ufo

Comment: @Ṃųỻịgǻňạcểơửṩ - gone forever, mostly. Even though SE reverted the change after the backlash, SO explicitly has the new icon. Don't ask me why, though

Comment: @Ṃųỻịgǻňạcểơửṩ The UFO took the spaceship, and returned back to their planet, they hated Stack Exchange. ;)

Comment: What's more likely is that they shot it down and took it to Area 51

Comment: @Ṃųỻịgǻňạcểơửṩ If you want the spaceship back, Oleg wrote a user script for it: [Save the waffles! Bringing back custom 404 pages to Stack Exchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/9058/save-the-waffles-bringing-back-custom-404-pages-to-stack-exchange). I believe you can even pick your own images for any of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: ^ I must note that user-overrides are not available for *every* site on the network, but for those I managed to find 404 images initially (which is most of them). (that said, now that the change is temporarily reverted, and Kevin was so kind as to find the rest of the images, it won't be long before you can customize any site of the network)